# Skipping Django test database creation for read-only, externally managed, high-security, big databases

Tags: django, database, testing, orm

We need to use real data for one of our many external data sources during Django tests:

- data is externally managed and read-only
- data is accessed through `manage.py inspectdb` generated ORM classes
- data is highly sensitive and we are not allowed to store fixtures of the actual data
- tables are legacy design and will be phased out, hundreds of tables with complex relations, even getting a single record is complex
- there is too much to do and I am unwilling to spend the time it would take to generate the fixtures, guarantee they're obfuscated, get approval of the obfuscation and justify keeping it around just to bridge us for a few months

We understand the downsides: This violates test purity and introduces a potential safety risk. We are willing to compromise on both to get us past the next few months when we will phase out this problem data source.

In this case, I need Django to understand that I don't want it to stand up a test database for this source, and just use the actual source so we can run some quick checks and walk away.

What is the simplest way to achieve this, with full understanding and acceptance of the risks and recommendations against?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For us, the solution was a custom test runner.

With help from [Django's Advanced Testing Topics documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks), we overrode the default `DiscoverRunner` like this:

```py
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


def should_create_db(db_name):
    # analyse db_name, a key from DATABASES, to determine whether a test
    # database should be created
    return db_name != 'messy_legacy_database'


class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    
    # override method from superclass to selectively skip database setup
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        # 'aliases' is a set of unique keys from settings DATABASES dictionary
        aliases = kwargs.get('aliases')
        filtered = set([i for i in aliases if should_create_db(i)])
        kwargs['aliases'] = filtered
        # 'aliases' now contains only keys which trigger test database creation
        return super().setup_databases(**kwargs)

    # there was no need to override teardown_databases()
```

Next we update `settings.py` to use our override instead of the default runner:

```py
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.CustomTestRunner'
```

Finally we tell our test class which databases it can use:

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class OurTest(TestCase):
    databases = [
        'default',
        'messy_legacy_database',
    ]

    def test_messy_legacy_database(self):
        # go nuts on your messy legacy database testing calls
        pass
```

In this way our tests now skip test database creation for our messy legacy databases, and the logic we test pulls data from the actual data sources, allowing us to implement quick checks to ensure these code paths work.

Comment: Nice, thanks!! `runner_should_create_test` in the class should be `should_create_db`. It seems important that "databases" include the "default".